# Is it able to avoid UndecidableInstances in this example?

Tags: haskell, undecidable-instances

I am trying to implement binary tree as a typeclass:

```hs
class BinaryTree bt where
    empty :: bt a -> Bool
    empty = isNothing . root
    emptyTree :: bt a
    branch :: a -> bt a -> bt a -> bt a 
    root :: bt a -> Maybe a
    lbranch :: bt a -> bt a 
    rbranch :: bt a -> bt a
```

And I want to illustrate that binary trees are data containers using this definition:

```hs
instance BinaryTree bt => Functor bt where
    fmap f bt = case root bt of
        Nothing -> emptyTree
        Just a -> branch (f a) (f <$> lbranch bt) (f <$> rbranch bt)
```

I've got:

```bash
BinaryTree/BinaryTree.hs:18:10: error:
    • The constraint ‘BinaryTree bt’
        is no smaller than the instance head ‘Functor bt’
      (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Functor bt’
```

Using `UndecidableInstances` absolutely makes the code compile. But I am wondering that is this a proper case to use `UndecidableInstances`?
I've read about articles like "When is UndecidableInstances safe?", but I do not really get it.

---

Update 1: About "Why using typeclasses"

It is a part of an exploration, in which I try to distinct complete binary trees and perfect binary trees from general binary trees by Haskell code, in a proper way, by describing the property of them in Haskell code. (The properties are: 1) complete binary trees are one-to-one correspond to lists, `bt2list` and `list2bt` are available, and 2) perfect binary trees is the combine of two same-depth perfect binary trees. )

Specifically, the ultimate goal is to declare a type for complete binary trees, that refuses a value which is a binary tree but not a complete binary tree when compiling. (And also for perfect binary trees.)

The exploration is still not given up  and suggestions are welcomed. Many thanks!

Comment: Do you really need this class? Consider `data [a] = [] | a : [a]` (pseudo-Haskell syntax) vs `class List lst where head :: lst a -> ... `. We use the former, not the latter.

Comment: Thats for your reply! It helps a lot. As for "Why using classes", see the update1 of this question.  @n.m.willseey'allonReddit

Comment: On your Update 1: to get the compiler to reject incorrect trees, you are almost certainly going to have to track the depth of the tree at the type level. This means trees of different depths *will have different types* -- and so your typeclass, which demands the same type for all the tree arguments/returns in its various functions, will not have these trees as instances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## On undecidable instances

`UndecidableInstances` is a mostly harmless extension. Don't worry if you have to turn it on.

In the worst case, `UndecidableInstances` can make the compiler get stuck in an infinite loop if you happen to have mutually depending instances, such as

```
instance A t => B t where ...
instance B t => A t where ...
```

If you are careful to avoid that, the compiler will just work fine.

The extension has no ill effects on the compiled code, only on the compilation itself. If your code compiles, you are safe.

## On overlapping instances

On the other side, this *is* something to worry

```
instance BinaryTree bt => Functor bt where
```

The head of this instance is `Functor t` and that overlaps with any other instances for `Functor`. That is to be avoided.

Haskell instance resolution performs *no backtracking* at all, since that can lead to an exponential blow up in compilation time, and break separate compilation. There is no sane way to write something like

```
instance MyClass1 f => Functor f where ...
instance MyClass2 f => Functor f where ...
```

To make this work, when resolving `Functor X`, Haskell should first try to resolve `MyClass1 X`, and if that fails try `MyClass2 X`. This turns out to be too problematic in practice.

Note that Haskell allows instances to be declared in any module. So to check "no instance for `MyClass1 X`" Haskell would need to read all the modules in your program. This would prevent the compiler to compile a module at a time, so it's disallowed.

So, an instance like

```
instance MyClass1 f => Functor f where ...
```

actually means "If you are resolving `Functor X`, you must have `MyClass X`. If you don't, fail". It's not an implication but more like an "if and only if". The compiler commits to the first instance whose head (the `Functor f` part) matches. The instance context (the `MyClass1 f =>` part) is not considered until the compiler has committed.

There are some ways to relax the constraints on overlapping instances, but I don't recommend those. They're very fragile if you don't precisely understand what's going on under the hood.

## Conclusion

To avoid the overlap, you could use a newtype wrapper:

```
newtype F f a = F (f a)
instance BinaryTree bt => Functor (F bt) where
```

Even if it's not equivalent, you could specify a functor superclass:

```
class Functor bt => BinaryTree bt where ...
```

This will force new instances to ensure trees are functors.

Perhaps more importantly, you should also consider to avoid using type classes at all for this task. It's pretty unusual in Haskell to declare a type class unless you have several instances in mind. In your case, your `class` seems to be a single type: a binary tree. All its instances will be essentially the same type. So, why using classes at all?

Comment: Thats for your answer! It helps a lot. As for "Why using typeclasses", see the update1 of this question. 